# How i can creat link to text and image in Rails 3?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to achieve the following HTML render code for a logo from Rails 3:

```
<a href="home.html" title="Return Home" class="logo">
   <img width="209" height="50" alt="home page" src="images/home-logo.png">
</a>
```

Where "home.html" is an action belongs to a controller.
I have searched online and found different solutions and nothing worked for me. IS there any way for doing so with less code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Rails API for `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and the [Rails API for `image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

The result should look similar to:

```
link_to(
  image_tag('home-logo.png', :size => "209x50"),
  {:controller => "pages", :action => "home"},
  :class => "logo",
  :title => "Return Home")
```

Not really shorter, but the Rails way to write it down.

Comment: Thanks Mliebelt, I need to add controller and action in dynamic way. I mentioned "home" is my action and lets say controller is "pages".

I after reading the API i would add {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}, Am I right?

Comment: I have changed my answer to match your (additional) requirements :-)

Comment: hahaha, I knew the answer after reading API (thanks to you ;) ), and i didn't want to add an answer by me and accept mine as the final one. I wanted you to get the right credit :)

Thanks again.